# fetchProvidersForEmail returning undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check if an email exists by using `fetchProvidersForEmail`, however the function that I've written keeps returning undefined.

```
var emailExists = (emailAddress) => {
firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(emailAddress)
    .then((providers) => {
    return providers.length > 0;
    });
};
```

In addition to this, I have also tried

```
var emailExists = (emailAddress) => {
    var exists = false;

    firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(emailAddress)
        .then((providers) => {
        exists = providers.length > 0;
        });

    return exists;
};
```

When replacing `return ...` with `console.log(providers.length > 0)` the value that I expect is returned. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
 var emailExists = (emailAddress) => {   
 return firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(emailAddress)
     .then((providers) => {
     return providers.length > 0;
     }); };
```

firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail returns a promise with the boolean of whether providers.length > 0 or not.

But in your emailExists function, you didn't return the promise. So undefined is returned.

Comment: Note that the method is now called fetchSignInMethodsForEmail